# Differential of the product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative, differential-forms, products

From Muirhead, *Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory*, pages 56-57.

> For any matrix $X$, $\text{d}X$ denotes the matrix of differential ($\text{d}x_{ij}$). It's easy to check that if $X$ is a $n\times m$ and $Y$ is $m\times p$ then
> \begin{equation}\text{d}(XY)=X.\text{d}Y+\text{d}X.Y\end{equation}

I'm trying to figure out what kind of product is involved in the previous expression. In order to do that, I've tried to see what happen in the simple case $n\triangleq m\triangleq p\triangleq 2$.

### example

If $n\triangleq m\triangleq p\triangleq 2$ then
\begin{equation}X=\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix} \qquad \text{d}X=\begin{bmatrix}
\text{d}x_{11} & \text{d}x_{12} \\
\text{d}x_{21} & \text{d}x_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}\quad Y=\begin{bmatrix}
y_{11} & y_{12} \\
y_{21} & y_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix} \qquad \text{d}Y=\begin{bmatrix}
\text{d}y_{11} & \text{d}y_{12} \\
\text{d}y_{21} & \text{d}y_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
I start from
\begin{equation}
XY=\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11}y_{11}+x_{12}y_{21} & x_{11}y_{12}+x_{12}y_{22} \\
x_{21}y_{11}+x_{22}y_{21} & x_{21}y_{12}+x_{22}y_{22}
\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
then, I compute the differential of $XY$ element-wise. By recalling that for a scalar function $f(x)$ with $x=[x_1, \dots, x_n]'$, its differential in $x$ is defined as
\begin{equation}\text{d}f(x)\triangleq \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial\,f(x)}{\partial\, x_k}\text{d}x_k\end{equation}
follows that for the first term of $\text{d}(XY)$ (element in position $i,j=1,1$) holds
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\text{d}(x_{11}y_{11}+x_{12}y_{21})&=\text{d}(x_{11}y_{11})+\text{d}(x_{12}y_{21})\\
&=(y_{11}\text{d}x_{11}+x_{11}\text{d}y_{11})
+(y_{21}\text{d}x_{12}+x_{12}\text{d}y_{21})\\
&=y_{11}\text{d}x_{11}+x_{11}\text{d}y_{11}
+y_{21}\text{d}x_{12}+x_{12}\text{d}y_{21}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
so, with the same reasoning applied to the others 3 elements, follows
\begin{equation}
\text{d}(XY)=\begin{bmatrix}
y_{11}\text{d}x_{11}+x_{11}\text{d}y_{11}
+y_{21}\text{d}x_{12}+x_{12}\text{d}y_{21}
&
y_{12}\text{d}x_{11}+x_{11}\text{d}y_{12}
+y_{22}\text{d}x_{12}+x_{12}\text{d}y_{22}\\
y_{11}\text{d}x_{21}+x_{21}\text{d}y_{11}
+y_{21}\text{d}x_{22}+x_{22}\text{d}y_{21} 
&
y_{12}\text{d}x_{21}+x_{21}\text{d}y_{12}
+y_{22}\text{d}x_{22}+x_{22}\text{d}y_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
which can be written, by separating the differentials, as
\begin{equation}\text{d}(XY)=
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{11}\text{d}x_{11}+y_{21}\text{d}x_{12} &
y_{12}\text{d}x_{11}+y_{22}\text{d}x_{12} \\
y_{11}\text{d}x_{21}+y_{21}\text{d}x_{22} &
y_{12}\text{d}x_{21}+y_{22}\text{d}x_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11}\text{d}y_{11}+x_{12}\text{d}y_{12} &
x_{11}\text{d}y_{12}+x_{12}\text{d}y_{22} \\
x_{21}\text{d}y_{11}+x_{22}\text{d}y_{21} &
x_{21}\text{d}y_{12}+x_{22}\text{d}y_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
In conclusion, it seems to me that
\begin{equation}\text{d}X.Y=\begin{bmatrix}
y_{11}\text{d}x_{11}+y_{21}\text{d}x_{12} &
y_{12}\text{d}x_{11}+y_{22}\text{d}x_{12} \\
y_{11}\text{d}x_{21}+y_{21}\text{d}x_{22} &
y_{12}\text{d}x_{21}+y_{22}\text{d}x_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\text{d}Y.X=\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11}\text{d}y_{11}+x_{12}\text{d}y_{12} &
x_{11}\text{d}y_{12}+x_{12}\text{d}y_{22} \\
x_{21}\text{d}y_{11}+x_{22}\text{d}y_{21} &
x_{21}\text{d}y_{12}+x_{22}\text{d}y_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
In theese two expressions I don't recognise any type of matricial product between $\text{d}X$, $Y$ or between $\text{d}Y$, $X$ (not the usual product "rows times columns", nor the [Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) or [Kronecker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) products).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the condition is
$$\mathrm{d}(\bf{A} \bf{B}) = \mathrm{d}\bf{A} .\bf{B}+\bf{A}.\mathrm{d}\bf{B}  $$

So,
\begin{align}
\text{LHS}_{ij} &=\mathrm{d} \sum_k A_{ik}B_{kj} \\
&=  \sum_k \mathrm{d} (A_{ik}B_{kj} + A_{ik}B_{kj}) \\
&= \sum_k  (\mathrm{d}A_{ik}B_{kj} + A_{ik}\mathrm{d}B_{kj}) \\
&= \sum_k \mathrm{d} A_{ik}B_{kj} + \sum_k A_{ik}\mathrm{d}B_{kj} \\
&= \text{RHS}_{ij}
\end{align}

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks for your help.I didn't recognise that it was the standard product "rows times columns" because in $\text{d}X.Y$ the differential and non differential terms are switched in position, while for $\text{d}Y.X$ the differential and non differential terms are in corrected position but $\text{d}Y.X$ is wrongly written in place of $\text{d}X.Y$

Comment: Yes, you got it!